# Understanding vector functions and line integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

When we talk about the line integral

$$\int \overrightarrow v \cdot d \overrightarrow l $$

(where $\overrightarrow v$ is a vector function), the vector function is giving us tons of vectors. What's happening is that each vector is being multiplied by the infinitesimal displacement towards the next vector. Is it correct to say that the **point** that the vector is describing is being multiplied by the infinitesimal displacement? Or how do I picture this?

I'm very much so a visual learner, so I'm trying to imagine how this all works. I like the way we illustrate regular 2-D integration as the sum of infinitesimally thin rectangles. This is really good for a visual learner because we can think ''area of the base x height''.

Comment: You can think it as adding up the components of $v$ tangent to the curve (over which you are integrating) at each point of that curve

Comment: Have you seen [this animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#/media/File:Line_integral_of_vector_field.gif) from Wikipedia?

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing a line integral, your infinitesimals are no longer distances or lengths -- they are actually vectors.

You can think of the underlying mechanism here as being *projection* of your vector $\vec{v}(\vec{x})$ onto your infinitesimal displacement vector $d\vec{\ell}(\vec{x})$.

That's why these integrals are great for representing work done by a force field on a moving object: the field is applying some force in some direction. You figure out how much of this force is in the direction of movement at each point (you project force onto your infinitesimal displacement). Then, you "sum" all of these up (integrate).

Does that help?

Comment: And the projection of one vector onto the other essentially just means that one vector is casting a ''shadow'' onto the other and we must find the length of this shadow, correct?

Comment: Yep!  Another way you can think about it is this: think of $\vec{v}$ as your actual motion, and $\vec{w}$ as the only direction you actually care about.  The projection of $\vec{v}$ onto $\vec{w}$ answers the question: when I make the motion $\vec{v}$, how much have I moved in the direction of $\vec{w}$?  

Think of $\vec{w}$ as the direction of the race's finish line, and $\vec{v}$ as the direction you ran.  How much closer to the finish line did your diagonal run get you?